# Pasar datos en hebreo de PHP a Android

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

Estoy tratando de pasar una lista de datos de `Mysql` a `Android`. Una parte de esa Lista esta escrita en Hebreo y esta guardada en hebreo con codificación de **utf8**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando imprimo esa lista en Json me salen símbolos de preguntas:

```
 [{"Img_ID":"10","Img_root":"images\/beatriz63_19_11_2018_11_56_40.jpg","U_Name":"beatriz63","localname":"????? ?? ??? ??????","zone":"???? ?? ????","category":"????","latitude":"32.0964625","longitude":"34.7741963","comment":"","thisDate":"2018-11-19 11:56:40"},{"Img_ID":"12","Img_root":"images\/beatriz63_19_11_2018_12_25_35.jpg","U_Name":"beatriz63","localname":"???????","zone":"???? ?? ????","category":"????","latitude":"32.0740769","longitude":"34.7922028","comment":"??????","thisDate":"2018-11-19 12:25:35"},{"Img_ID":"13","Img_root":"images\/beatriz63_19_11_2018_12_58_38.jpg","U_Name":"beatriz63","localname":"??? ????? ????","zone":"???? ????","category":"?????","latitude":"32.439070099999995","longitude":"34.878046499999996","comment":"??? ?????? ???? ???? ?????","thisDate":"2018-11-19 12:58:38"},{"Img_ID":"14","Img_root":"images\/beatriz63_19_11_2018_13_11_44.jpg","U_Name":"beatriz63","localname":"?????","zone":"???? ?? ????","category":"????","latitude":"32.0725869","longitude":"34.778971399999996","comment":"","thisDate":"2018-11-19 13:11:44"},{"Img_ID":"15","Img_root":"images\/beatriz63_19_11_2018_13_56_24.jpg","U_Name":"beatriz63","localname":"????? ?? ????","zone":"???? ?? ????","category":"????","latitude":"32.072392","longitude":"34.786619","comment":"","thisDate":"2018-11-19 13:56:24"},{"Img_ID":"16","Img_root":"images\/beatriz63_20_11_2018_00_13_57.jpg","U_Name":"beatriz63","localname":"???? ?? ?? ????","zone":"???? ????","category":"???","latitude":"31.55979881924014","longitude":"35.40268298238516","comment":"","thisDate":"2018-11-20 00:13:57"}]
```

Este es mi código `PHP`:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<?PHP
    $hostname_localhost="localhost";
    $database_localhost="photogo";
    $username_localhost="root";
    $password_localhost="Root1234";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");
    $myArray = array();
    mysql_query("SET character_set_client = 'utf8';");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_result = 'utf8';");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Img_ID,Img_root,U_Name,localname,zone,category,latitude,longitude,comment,thisDate FROM dataimage")) {
        //$myArray =array("imagedata");

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $myArray []= $row;
        }

        $result->close();
    }else{
        $row["i_id"]=0;
        $row["Img_root"]="No Result";
        $row["U_Name"]="No Result";
        $row["category"]="No Result";
        $row["localname"]="No Result";
        $row["zone"]="No Result";
        $row["category"]="No Result";
        $row["latitude"]=0;
        $row["logitude"]=0;
        $row["comment"]="No Result";
        $row["thisdate"]="No Result";
        $myArray['imagedata'][]=$row;
     }

     //echo hebrev (json_encode($myArray));
    echo json_encode($myArray);

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Eh tratado de hacer de todo pero aun no consigo como pasar esos signos al hebreo.

Comment: Intenta usar `json_encode( $myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );` [constantes json](http://se2.php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php)

Comment: Tambien lo intente y nada